# Какие знаки может содержать varchar в postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Интересует какие знаки может содержать varchar в postgres? Насколько я понимаю абсолютно все без ограничений но гугл мне не помогает(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Набор символов базы данных определяет набор символов, который используется для хранения текстовых значений ([8.3. Символьные типы](http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/datatype-character.html)). То есть тип varchar может хранить символы той кодировки, которая выбрана при создании базы данных. Возможные наборы [можно посмотреть в документации (22.3. Character Set Support)](http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/multibyte.html).